# Haskell String Decode

Tags: string, function, haskell

I want to make two functions which replaces a letter in a string with it's pair.
For exemple:

```
  input: abcd
  output: qwer
```

The other function does the same thing backwards:

```
  input: qwer
  output: abcd
```

```
abc :: String
abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
qwe :: String
qwe = "qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the first half:

```hs
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

-- your input
abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
kod = "qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm"

-- make a map from those
charMap = Map.fromList $ zip abc kod

-- use this map to encode a single char:
encodeChar c = fromJust $ Map.lookup c charMap

-- use this function to encode a String (= list of Chars)
encode = map encodeChar
```

---

#### Example:

```hs
encode "abcde"
> "qwert"

---
```

With this you should be able to make the second function yourself.

### Got stuck?

Try to lookup the functions you don't know on [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) - for example [Map.lookup](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#v:lookup).

Also you should try to add the type signatures - paste the code into GHCi and ask it for the types if you don't know at once.

Make sure you know what is happening with the definition of `encode` ;)

Also note that this (the `fromJust`) will throw an expection if you call it outside the range (try `encode "Hello!"`) - if you want try to fix this ;)